# Read value from XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm having trouble to query XML from the database. The original column in the database is of the type `ntext`, but an XML text is stored in this column.

When I cast the column to `xml` type, this is one of the results:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.desoft.de/activerepo/fileprops">
  <props>
    <prop ns="ARM:" elem="_NoFilter">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="displayname">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">RE: Demande de Rendez vous pour le 31 Janvier</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="getcontenttype">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">message/rfc822</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="creationdate">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2018-10-18T18:41:41.3993879</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="account">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">mailjournal@gg.com</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="journal">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="box">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Inbox</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="onlyattachments">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="user">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">mailjournal@gg.com</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="urn:schemas:httpmail:" elem="attachments">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </prop>
    ...
  </props>
</root>
```

Now I have to read single node values from the `xml` column, but actually this does not work and I don't know why.

```
select
    top 10
    cast(properties as xml),
    cast(properties as xml).value('(/props/prop[@elem="displayname"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') as testRead,
    *
from   
       tm_cas_files f (nolock)
where
       properties is not null     
       and id = '64A663EF-A466-4EB0-97DC-94554ADFDFC9'
```

If I try to read the `xml` this way, the column `testRead` is always `null`. What can I try next?

Comment: What is the expected result here? Also, why are you still using `ntext`? It's been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005.

Comment: It's not me using `ntext`. it is from a system we are using. I can't change this. The expected result is the value `RE: Demande de Rendez vous pour le 31 Janvier` from the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now made it work with your clues. The additional problem was that there were line breaks in the `XML` text. These had to be removed as well. Also the `xml` declaration was part of the text. This I removed as well. Then it worked. Here is the final code:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.desoft.de/activerepo/fileprops', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd)
select
    top 10
    cast(replace(replace(cast(properties as nvarchar(max)),CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),''),'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>','') as xml).value('(root/props/prop[@elem="from"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from   
       tm_cas_files f (nolock)
where
       properties is not null     
       and id = '64A663EF-A466-4EB0-97DC-94554ADFDFC9'
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your default namespace here, as it's declared in your XML. This gets you the result you want:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleTable (nXML ntext);
INSERT INTO dbo.SampleTable (nXML)
VALUES 
(N'<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.desoft.de/activerepo/fileprops">
  <props>
    <prop ns="ARM:" elem="_NoFilter">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="displayname">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">RE: Demande de Rendez vous pour le 31 Janvier</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="getcontenttype">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">message/rfc822</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="creationdate">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2018-10-18T18:41:41.3993879</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="account">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">mailjournal@gg.com</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="journal">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="box">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Inbox</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="onlyattachments">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="tm:mail:" elem="user">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">mailjournal@gg.com</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="urn:schemas:httpmail:" elem="attachments">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </prop>
    ...
  </props>
</root>');

GO
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.desoft.de/activerepo/fileprops', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd)
SELECT X.XMLData.value('(root/props/prop[2]/value/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS [value]
FROM dbo.SampleTable ST
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(xml,ST.nXML))) X(XMLData);

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.SampleTable;
GO
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it did not succeed. The value was even `null`

Comment: What did you run? If you run the full the fll SQL I've provided returns the value `RE: Demande de Rendez vous pour le 31 Janvier`, @dns_nx . This mean that the SQL you have used isn't correct.

Comment: @dns_nx [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9be4ab1c56b24174251a234c2000961a)

Comment: `With XmlNamespaces(Default 'http://www.desoft.de/activerepo/fileprops', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd)
Select
    Top 10
    cast(properties as xml),
    cast(properties as xml).value('
    (/root/props/prop[@elem="displayname"]/value)[1]' , 'nvarchar(255)') as testRead,
    *
From
       tm_cas_files f (nolock)
Where
       properties is not null
       and id = '64A663EF-A466-4EB0-97DC-94554ADFDFC9'`
works for me. The two changes to OP's code are just (1) correct the path and (2) add the namespace

Answer (score -1):

Using [XMLQuire](http://www.qutoric.com/xmlquire/) to play with your xml tells me that the path to your answer starts with `root` :

```
/root/props/prop[2]/value
```

so you want `'(/root/props/prop[@elem="displayname"]/value)[1]'`

[image: XMLQuire has point-and-click 'show me the XPAth']

Comment: How does help the OP get the data using T-SQL?

Comment: You're never going to get a non-null result out of the SQL if the xpath is wrong?

Comment: No, that isn't true. If you use the wrong namespace, you will. If you take my answer, and comment out the line starting `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, the return value will be `NULL`. But this answer doesn't help the OP on how to use XQuery, just tells them the node that the value is in. There's no detail on how they would get that value from the xml afterwards.

Comment: @Larnu I agree that the namespace is missing and yes that will also prevent a result. Equally, saying that the namespace is missing but ignoring the incorrect path is also only half way there? Secondly, a point-and-click tool saves hours when still on the xml learning curve.